# Regex to match closing quote followed by letter

Tags: regex, quotes

I'm writing a text formatting routine that will insert spaces wherever applicable and I'm struggling to construct a regular expression that will match closing quote (double <strike>or single</strike>) symbol followed by a letter. For example:

```
first " closing double quote" should not match, but "the second one"should.
```

Here the space should be inserted only after the second closing quote. So far I've got

```
(["']).*?\1(?![^\p{L}])
```

with intention to use a named group for the backreference part and go from there injecting my space, but this matches whole

```
"closing double quote" should not match, but "
```

instead of

```
"the second one"
```

What magic shall I apply here? I'm using .Net 4.5 if that makes any difference.

Update: Having played with some test data I realized that it's not quite possible to reliably distinguish single quote from an apostrophe, so the question should now read "double quotes" instead of "single or double quotes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern it works for either single and double closing quotes not followed by a white space in the same string

```
"(?!\s)(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)|'(?!\s)(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/243)

Comment: This is great if I replace \s with [^\p{L}] which seems to give me the result I need.

Comment: or use `\P{L}` instead of `\s`

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like a tough one. Here you go,

```
(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?=\p{L}(?:\1(?:(?!\1).)*+\1|[^'"])*$)
```

Use the above regex and then replace the matched characters with `$0<space>`.

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/wuYSwfpqEY)

- `(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1` Matches a single or double quoted string only if it's followed by,
- `\p{L}` Any letter from any language.
- `(?:\1(?:(?!\1).)*+\1|[^'"])*`  double quoted string ("foo") or single quoted string ('foo') or not of double or single quotes (f,o,o), zero or more times.
- `$` End of the line anchor.

Comment: This works very good if I remove either the "+" or the "*" quantifier (otherwise Expresso complaints about syntax). Only the end of line anchor looks somewhat like a hack. Ideally I would like it to work with quoted strings spawned to multiple lines as well.

Comment: try `(?s)(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?=\p{L}(?:\1(?:(?!\1).)*+\1|[^'"])*$)`

Comment: This is better subject to removing "+". I'll try to modify it to work with double quotes only as per my revision of the question.

Comment: then `(?s)"[^"]*"(?=\p{L}(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion will work if you do not have any abnormal spacing in your input. You can add spaces around quoted strings (single and double quotes are supported:

```
  var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\s*)((['""])(?!\3).+?\3)\s*", " $2 ");
```

Tested in Expresso:

```
Input:
 - First "closing double quote" should not match, but "the second one"should. 
 - First 'closing double quote' should 'the "second" one'should.

Output:
 - First "closing double quote" should not match, but "the second one" should. 
 - First 'closing double quote' should 'the "second" one' should.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, I would use something like this:

`".*?"(.)`

You can then simply check capture group 1 and see if it is a space or not.

You can repeat with

`'.*?'(.)`

If you want to do the same for single quotes.

Example:

https://www.debuggex.com/r/5Ibzv2UbhcZXxW9n